# Scala like JDBC ConnectionPool.singleton 's exception is unable to be caught catch block

Tags: mysql, scala, jdbc

My mysql is down so it should throw error which should be caught in catch block. But it doesn't.

```
try {
        Class.forName(driver)
        ConnectionPool.singleton(url, username, password)
    }
    catch {
      case _ => logger.error("Unable to connect to Database")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your exception is ignored with `Try(...)` statement.

If you check value of your `connection` variable, it's most likely be smth like `Failure(... exception ... )`

Comment: I have edited the code : The exception is generated from ConnectionPool.singleton

Comment: so what is happening after edit, no exception at all?

Comment: Exception is same, but the exception is not caught in catch block. Even debugger doesn't stops there.       ConnectionPool.singleton(url, username, password) the line where exception is generated

Comment: Using scalalikejdbc

Comment: maybe your logger configured incorrectly. try `println`

Comment: even if that's the case then also it should'nt throw exception further. My question is ...it is not going into catch block

Comment: it's not possible.. publish whole code. `case _` catch all `Throwables`. It should definetly goes there.

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Comment: Does it have anything to do with this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113614/discussion-between-pushpendra-jaiswal-and-rumoku).